Visualization of Polynomials and Algebraic Numbers
I'm studying Field Extension Theory and Galois Theory, and unlike (for example) studying Linear Algebra, the concepts feel very much like manipulation of symbols, and I don't feel to have a very strong intuitive judge inside me to say when a theorem is true or not. Besides, I have to present this content to an audience who don't study pure math.
In Linear Algebra, I can see clearly what the algebraic manipulation represents in the form of visualizations (thanks to 3b1b's playlist "Essence of Linear Algebra")
I was trying to find/come-up-with a visualization for the most elementary but fundamental definition in field extension theory which is "what is a polynomial?"
I know the formal definition of a polynomial, but I haven't been able to imagine it geometrically in anyway, let alone visualize what it means for a number to be algebraic (noting that I also know the formal definition). I tried to look up "Geometric Representation of Algebraic Numbers," but I couldn't find satisfying answers.
I thought of straightedge and compass constructions, and also visualizing polynomials as a vector space, but to no avail, since these imaginations don't seem like they make things easier.
I heard that I may get some insight from Algebraic Geometry, but this seems to hard for me to study for the time being.
Any help is appreciated.

The beautiful theory of dessins d'enfants partially answers your request. Partially because the insights are not as straightforward as in linear algebra and they work only on a certain class of polynomials and other rational functions. However, they are as visual as a thing can be.
What is a dessin d'enfant? From one point of view, it is a bipartite graph embedded cellularly on an orientable and closed surface. To be embedded cellularly means that the complement of the embedding is a disjoint union of regions homeomorphic to an open disk. The simplest examples come from bipartite planar graphs (even the "bipartite" can be dropped if a certain convention is assumed). In particular, the simplest possible class is the class of all trees.
From another point of view, a dessin d'enfant is a ramified covering $f\colon X\to\mathbb{CP}^1$ of the Riemann sphere, ramified over a subset of $\{0,1,\infty\}$. Here $X$ is a compact Riemann surface. The simplest examples come from polynomials $f\colon \mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ such that $f$ is a polynomial sending infinity to infinity and has $\{0,1\}$ as critical values. Such a polynomial is called a Shabat polynomial.
The link between these points of view is among the most beautiful theorems that I have encountered in 2 decades of pursuing mathematics:
Theorem (Belyi's theorem and Grothendieck's correspondence). There is a 1-1 correspondence between (equivalence classes of) bipartite graphs cellularly embedded on orientable closed surfaces and (equivalence classes of) pairs $(X,f)$ where $X$ is a compact Riemann surface and $f\colon X\to\mathbb{CP}^1$ a ramified cover of the Riemann sphere ramified over a subset of $\{0,1,\infty\}$, both defined over $\overline{\mathbb Q}$.
One obtains a cellularly embedded bipartite graph from $(X,f)$ by declaring $f^{-1}(0)$ to be the black vertices, $f^{-1}(1)$ to be the white vertices and $f^{-1}((0,1))$ the edges. The other direction is more elaborate but not difficult. The part about being defined over $\overline{\mathbb Q}$ is Belyi's theorem.
Hence Shabat polynomials correspond to trees, and (certain) meromorphic maps correspond to planar graphs. The equivalence is valid in any genus, but I will not go into detail.
But, this is not even the most beautiful part yet. The Belyi-Grothendieck correspondence stipulates that $(X,f)$ must be defined over algebraic numbers, hence there is an action of the absolute Galois group over $\mathbb Q$ on the "defining coefficients" of $X$ and $f$.
If we look at the simple example of trees, this means that the corresponding pair $(X,f)$ is given by $(\mathbb C\cup \{\infty\},f)$ where $f$ is a Shabat polynomial with coefficients in $\overline{\mathbb Q}$.
An explicit example is $f\colon z\mapsto z^3(z^2 -2z + a)$, where $a=\frac{34 + 6\sqrt{27}}{7}$. Hence $f$ is defined over $Q(\sqrt{21})$ and there is a nontrivial Galois symmetry $\sigma\colon\sqrt{21}\mapsto-\sqrt{21}$. Hence when $\sigma$ acts on $f$ we obtain $f^\sigma = z^3(z^2 -2z + \sigma(a))$. The corresponding trees obtained by taking the preimage of $[0,1]$ look like

What you are looking at is a visual representation of the action of the absolute Galois group over $\mathbb Q$! In fact, this action is faithful, hence $\text{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb Q}/\mathbb Q)$ can be seen as a "permutation group" acting on dessins d'enfants!
You can notice that both trees have the same number of black vertices, same number of white vertices, same number of edges, and even the same degree sequence. This is not a coincidence - it is a general rule, even in higher genus! Hence this action has invariants which can be seen, and one of the central goals of the theory of dessins d'enfants is to identify these "visible" invariants.

I don't see how this makes visualizing Galois Groups and field extensions easier. Here, we're studying the action of a Galois Group, and so we don't speak about the Galois Group itself.
I don't see how this would make things easier for a non-mathematical audience.

I agree with your first sentence, hence why I say at the beginning that this is a partial answer whose insights are not as straight-forward as in linear algebra. I disagree about your comment on group action - groups are often studied by how they act on objects. In my opinion it is easier to understand e.g. a permutation group by how it acts rather than what its abstract structure is. For your last point, I also somewhat disagree. Dessins d'enfants are perhaps the only way to see how a Galois group acts without referring to minimal polynomials, monodromy, branch cuts, Riemann surfaces etc.

Are there any other resources that makes it easier for an undergraduate student in Math to study in a few days?

To study Galois theory? An introduction aiming to prove the unsolvability of quintics by radicals is typically a full semester course. The more geometric stuff like Riemann surfaces is usually a senior year or graduate level course.

You can take a look at "Abel’s Theorem in Problems and Solutions" by Alekseev based on Arnold's lectures to high school students of Moscow State University (this is/was a high school specializing in mathematics and physics so the level was much higher than in a typical school) where he proves the unsolvability of quintics by radicals. Arnold calls the proof 'geometric', but there's still a good amount of abstract algebra there.

No, I was asking specifically about studying dessin d'enfant, not Galois. I know Galois, I just can't imagine it :)

A great textbook style resource with all the details aimed at undergraduates is "Introduction to Compact Riemann Surfaces and Dessins d’Enfants" by Girondo and González-Diez is an introductory text aimed at undergraduates. If a student already knows about Riemann surfaces, they can skip to the last chapter about dessins d'enfats, which probably is doable in approx 10 days.

For a more "broad picture" approach where details are left out but the concepts and ideas are excellently presented, the first part of "Graphs on Surfaces and their Applications" by Lando and Zvonkin is a great book.
